# Doctrine2 table inheritance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I'm not sure of the term for what I'm looking for so please bear with me!

I have a table structure that looks like this:

```
[Branch]        [Ville]
- ID            - ID
- Ville_ID      - Region_ID

                [Region]
                - ID
                - Province_ID

                [Province]
                - ID
                - Country_ID

                [Country]
                - ID
```

The branch entity looks like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
class Succursale
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Hero\LieuBundle\Entity\Ville")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Ville_ID", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $ville;
}
```

The city, region, province and country entities are basically identical to each other:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
class Ville
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Hero\LieuBundle\Entity\Region")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Region_ID", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $region;
}
```

The code is simple (Symfony2):

```
$succursales = $entreprise->getSuccursales();
```

And in a twig template I have:

```
<ul>
{% for item in succursales %}
    <li>{{ item.adresse }}, {{ item.ville.nom }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This all works fine. When I fetch a branch, I can get the city without a hitch, but obviously it would be nice to be able to get the region, province and country with a single query. Seeing how awesome Doctrine2 is, I'm sure this is possible, but if anyone can point me in the right direction is would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The only way i see to do it with one query is to write your own customized query for the result you want to retrieve. Doctrine uses lazy loading to load the related objects when needed. You can disable lazy loading but that wont join all the tables, it will still run multiple queries. Anyways the 5 or so queries that will be run by no means should be an issues for your server unless you have massive, massive amounts of traffic and they dont look complex as well. If you are at that point that those kind of queries count to you, you should consider scratching off the ORM part of doctrine...

Comment: No, performance isn't an issue, for now at least. I guess I'll just write my own query. Thanks!